# Access the Main Scene / Layer from a class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have 3 different classes `Tree`, `Fruit`, and `Basket`. Each of them have their own `CCSprite` member that I access through `getSprite( )` ( each class has its own `getSprite( )` ). Also, each class has a `draw( )` method which sets the `CCSprite`'s texture, position, and other `CCSprite` related stuff. When I make an instance of these classes, I always need to `addChild( )` each of these sprites in the main layer. Nothing's actually wrong with it but I want it so that each `draw( )` method would be the one handling the `addChild( )` method to the main layer.

My code is like this:

```
// Tree.cpp
#include "Tree.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

Tree::Tree( ) {
   draw( );
}

CCSprite * Tree:getSprite( ) {
   return m_TreeSprite;
}
void Tree::draw( ) {
   m_TreeSprite = CCSprite::create( "tree.png" );
   m_TreeSprite -> setPosition ( 100, 100 );
}

/*
 * The other classes have similar structure. Will take a long long post if I write them all.
 */ 

// MainLayer.cpp
void MainLayer::drawScreenObjects( ) {
   m_Tree = Tree( );
   this -> addChild( m_Tree.getSprite( ) );

   m_Basket = Basket( );
   this -> addChild( m_Basket.getSprite( ) );
}
```

I want it so that the `draw( )` method could look similar to this:

```
void Tree::draw( ) {
   m_TreeSprite = CCSprite::create( "tree.png" );
   m_TreeSprite -> setPosition( 100, 100 );
   MainLayer -> addChild( m_TreeSprite );
}
```

Solutions I am thinking of are

1. Passing references to the `MainLayer` to every class and have a member variable hold that reference.
2. Making all classes inherit from CCNode so that they can have children of their own.

Any other possible solutions? I just feel my current setup is dirty and unstable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe Tree::drawOnParent(CCNode* parent){ parent->addChild(m_TreeSprite);} ?

Comment: @m.ding It might work but I'm calling `draw( )` from the class itself ( In `Tree`'s constructor ). Using that, I must pass a reference of the `MainLayer` to the class. I want these classes to do every bit of setting up by themselves when I create an instance, including the adding of `CCSprite`s in the `MainLayer`.

Comment: it is a bit long so I post it as an answer.

Comment: Having your game object inherit from CCNode or CCSprite is a good idea and is current practice. Also, if you inherit from CCNode/CCSprite, don't use the Draw method to create sprites and/or add childs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know any c++ but maybe try making a constructor with your MainLayer as a parameter then just calling addChild with the reference. You also wouldn't need a member variable to hold the reference, you can call removeFromParentAndCleanup instead.

You could also make a singleton object that holds a reference to the current MainLayer then you can call the singleton from anywhere, but that sounds more expensive. I would just go with your #1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

MainLayer.h

```
public:
static MainLayer* me = 0;
```

MainLayer.cpp in init()

```
MainLayer::me = this;
```

then in your draw()

```
if(MainLayer::me){
    MainLayer::me->addChild();
}
```

Comment: It's a static variable so does that mean I don't have to pass a reference of MainLayer around my app? Also, this is coming from my experiences in static stuff in Java but don't I need to declare the `draw( )` as `static` too?

Comment: No you don't need I guess, cannot remember clearly but I used similar code before. you draw() method are not need to be static.